# UITextView をコードで生成するとキャレットの開始位置が左上とならない

Tags: swift

UITextView のキャレットの開始位置を左上に持ってくることが目的です。

前提として言語は swift(ver 1.2)、Xcode 6.4、ターゲットはiOS 8.4です。
storyboard では画面遷移のみを定義し、xib にビューの定義（各コントロールの配置等）をして開発をしております。

UITextView を storyboard ではなく、コードもしくは xib で定義をするとキャレットの開始位置が左上ではなく、中途半端な位置に固定されてしまいます。

以下は UITextView を生成した際のコードです。

```
class hogeViewController: UIViewController, 
      UITableViewDelegate, 
      UITableViewDataSource{ 

      var myTextView = UITextView()

      override func viewDidLoad() { 


          myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 300,80)
          myTextView.layer.masksToBounds = true
          myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
          myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1
          myTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
          myTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

          self.view.addSubview(myTextView)
      }
}
```

この事象の対処法またはコードの不備等ございましたらご指摘いただきたいです。
よろしくお願い致します

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Xcodeのバージョン、ターゲットのiOSのバージョンを追記してください。Xcode 6.4、iOS 8.4では、`UITextView`のプロパティ`borderStyle`はないという警告が出ます。それと、御呈示のコードは、どこに書いてありますか？「`UIViewController`サブクラスの`viewDidLoad`メソッドに実装」という形で説明ください。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。
そして質問内容に関するご指摘誠にありがとうございます。

質問を編集いたしましたが、Xcode 6.4、ターゲットはiOS 8.4です。
また、コードは「UIV‌​iewControllerサブクラスのviewDidLoadメソッドに実装」となります。

Comment: 「回答」ではなく、コメントです。`myTextView.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect`の行に、赤色の警告は出ませんでしたか？再現できる事象でないと、その対処のしかたを導くことができません。赤色の警告が出たままでは、ビルドできないので、問題を再現することができません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。myTextView.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect を使用すると、UITextView にborderStyle というメンバが存在しません。というエラーになります。この部分をコメントアウトしてビルドしシュミレータで確認すると、事象が発生します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation Barの高さ分、Scroll Viewのコンテンツがインセットされるようです。`UITextView`も`UIScrollView`のサブクラスです。
*Storyboardで設置したScroll Viewでもインセットされます。*
**View Controller**のAttributes Inspectorで、「Adjust Scroll View Insets」のチェックを外すと、Navigation Barの高さ分のインセットが、無効になります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Storyboardでなく、コードで設定するならば、

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
// selfは、View Controllerのこと。
```

を、`viewDidLoad()`に加えるといいでしょう。

Comment: 色々と調査いただき、誠にありがとうございます。質問を編集し、画像を追加いたしました。画像だと、最下部にキャレットが表示されています。

Comment: @K.Watanabe ナビゲーションバーの高さ分、カーソル（キャレット？）位置がずれている印象を受けますね。ナビゲーションバーありの画面、なしの画面で比較してみてください。

Comment: @K.Watanabe 回答を更新しました。

Comment: 真摯にご対応いただき、誠にありがとございます。
後ほど、シュミレータにて確認させていただきます。

Comment: 度々、ありがとうございます。ご教授頂きました方法で解決できました。とても助かりました。